# How to encode file contents for Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()

Tags: post, parse-platform, httprequest

I have a file in my Parse Cloud data store.

I want to post this file along with some text data to a 3rd-party web server that accepts HTML Forms via POST. I'm getting the fileContents itself using this:

```
cvFilePtr = parseObj.get("file");
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({url:cvFilePtr.url()})
```

How to I use httpRequest to POST the file? Or more specifically, how do I encode fileContents?

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method:'POST',
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    url:'http://...',
    body:{
        'field':'some text',
        'file':magic(fileContents)
    }
}
```

Is there a function to replace **magic** in the code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse cloud code doesn't support `multipart/form-data`. You can check [here](https://www.facebook.com/parseit/videos/863104880446962/)

Comment: that's great! Finally a definitive answer.

Comment: and it sounds like there are no plans for Parse to add such support

Answer (score 0):

Vintesh found the answer, direct from a Parse.com employee ([Fosco Marotto](https://github.com/gfosco)), in a [video](https://www.facebook.com/parseit/videos/863104880446962/).

1. coverage starts at 2:46 into video
2. Parse platform has never supported POST requests of type multipart/form-data
3. Parse haven't had many requests for this functionality
4. Parse developer recommends using Parse.com Cloud hooks web functionality to call a service that does support "this kind of advanced stuff"